# Proper reconnect after WebSocketException

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-5

I use *ClientWebSocket* to connect to a socket server.
If I stop the server I got *WebSocketException* what is OK.
Then I try to reconnect.

If I use

```
await wsClient.ConnectAsync(serviceUri, cts.Token);
```

I get *"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The WebSocket has already been started.'"*

If I try to close it before reconnecting by

```
await wsClient.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
```

I get *"System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException: 'The WebSocket is in an invalid state ('Aborted') for this operation. Valid states are: 'Open, CloseReceived, CloseSent''
"*

So what is the proper way of reconnecting after the connection has been lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just run into the same problem. Apparently you cannot reuse an aborted `ClientWebSocket`. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket.abort?view=net-6.0#System_Net_WebSockets_ClientWebSocket_Abort) of `ClientWebSocket.Abort()` say:

> The `ClientWebSocket` cannot be reused once it is aborted.